# Which .pypirc file is used?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I've created a .pypirc file into my HOME directory (/home/myname/.pypirc)

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    local

[local]
repository: xxx
username: xxx
password: xxx
```

When I run

```
python setup.py register -r local
```

I've got the message

```
ValueError: local not found in .pypirc
```

But when I edit my setup.py by defining _get_rc_file to return ~/.pypirc then the execution is correct.

I wonder which .pypirc file is used when I don't define _get_rc_file and how can I find it?

Comment: What version of pypi are you using? `~/.pypirc` should be correct, could it be you're on an ancient version of pypi?

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)